# Home and End keys doesn't work in vim inside tmux

Tags: vim, cygwin, tmux, xterm

I can't use home and end keys in vim, when in Tmux. I've got this strange stuff:

```
H
F
H
sample text
```

my .tmux.conf:

```
set-option -g mode-mouse on
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-window on
set-option -g xterm-keys on # this one handles F keys in vim.
```

Comment: Use `^` (or `0`, depending on where you actually want to go) and `$`.

Comment: can you please explain how to use them? shift+6 doesn't work.. what those symbols means?

Comment: These are Vim's basic keybindings for "start of the line" and "end of the line". They are much better than `<home>` and `<end>`.

Comment: well to call `^` it's shift+6 right? this doesn't work.

Comment: There seems to be a bug somewhere. With certain values of TERM, it breaks. For me it breaks across all sessions in tmux even between different servers I'm SSH'd into.

My errant line (from .bashrc):
  alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux"